# Getting a reference to a boxed value type

Tags: c#, .net

Is there an easy way, perhaps with the System.Memory package, to obtain a (readonly) reference (as `ref T`, `in T`, `Span<T>` or `Memory<T>`) to the interior data stored in a boxed instance of a value type?

I have come up with this solution, but it requires to pin the object and to use `unsafe`.

```
object o = 1;
var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(o, GCHandleType.Pinned);
Span<int> span;
try
{
    var addr = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
    unsafe
    {
        span = new Span<int>(addr.ToPointer(), 1);
    }
} finally
{
    handle.Free();
}
ref int r = ref span[0];
```

Comment: a reference to the value type is an oxymoron. You can only use references to reference types...

Comment: @ZoharPeled `ref int` is a reference to a value type.

Comment: a boxed object is a reference, and you get access to the interiour by unboxing.
`object o = 1; int n = (int)o`. But your source code is leading in a complete different direction, more like managed/unmanaged memory. I think you want to ask another question. For any manipulation, just do your 'boxing' manually and explicit and not with the automatism provided by .NET.

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback yes, that's correct. What I meant was that a variable holding a value type actually holds the value itself, as apposed to a reference type where the variable holds a reference to the value. if you have `int x = 5` then `x` holds `5`, not a reference to `5`.

Comment: @ZoharPeled That is factually correct, but not relevant to the question.

Comment: @IllidanS4wantsMonicaback You ask a question about references, but show source code about pinning managed memory. No wonder you confuse people what to answer. Maybe you want a pinned pointer, not just a reference.

Comment: @Holger I showed a code that *does the thing I asked about*, but inefficiently - as you point out, it pins the reference, since `AddrOfPinnedObject` wouldn't work without that. The first paragraph is the question, not the code that follows. If people expect I come begging "help why my code not work", then perhaps it's better to ask for details or clarifications rather than jumping to conclusions.

Comment: @Holger I ask about a reference to the boxed value stored inside the object, not to the object itself (which of course I already have in `object o`). And even if that terminology is unclear to readers, I explicitly state I want to get it as a by-ref type (`ref T`) and then I reiterate I want the interior reference. I have never written "reference type", so I hope you understand my slight dissatisfaction if people just assume it is what I mean and think I don't know the terminology. Again, I ask about a *variable reference* not an *object reference*.

Comment: Never heard complains about answers on stackoverflow before. I have not really an answer, but if I have to deal with boxed values, I always create my own `class Box<T> { public T Value {get;set;}}`. This way all the implicit internal boxing staff is not used, and everything is explicit. If you know what to do with reference types or with value types, than the question for boxed types is obsolete this way.

Comment: @Holger Yes, that is always a possibility and preferable if I have control over the type I receive. But let's say I don't have another option. After all, in CIL the `unbox` instruction does precisely this, but C# doesn't expose the reference it creates.

Comment: OK, and your problem is you cannot use Reflection.Emit , cause you are on .NET Core. You should have added this Tag to the question in first place. I see you found an answer yourself.

Comment: @Holger Ah, that is a mistake on my part. I am not on .NET Core, but I was wondering about solutions that aren't as hacky (and thus possibly unsupported) as emitting custom code. I was hoping that with things like `ReadOnlySpan<T>` around, it would be simpler. Guess that is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Unsafe.Unbox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.unbox) is new in .NET Core 3.0 and is a simple wrapper over `unbox`, taking an object and returning it as `ref`. It is rightfully in the `Unsafe` class as the runtime doesn't allow mutating the boxed value by overwriting it with another value, i.e. the only changes to the contents must be allowed by the type itself (like for reference types). This is called a controlled-mutability pointer and it cannot be represented in the .NET type system (in C++ terms, imagine a pointer to a non-const object that strips `operator=` from its type when accessed).

For platforms that support emit, it is of course always possible to create a dynamic method with the `unbox` or `unbox_any` instruction. Violating the mutability constraint will make the code unverifiable however (like `Unsafe.Unbox` is).

Comment: Any reference for why the runtime does not allow mutation? Also I'd be interested why that rule would only apply to readonly fields. readonly is otherwise never enforced by the runtime.

Comment: OK, there is something in III.1.8.1.2.2 and in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe.unbox?view=net-5.0. What's in ECMA is a very, very weird rule. Simply the presence of *any* mutator method makes the type non-readonly. It does not matter if the method is even being used. This is clearly not thought through...

Comment: @usr I would interpret that in the other direction: absence of a mutator method/field makes the type strictly read-only, which is the direct consequence of the nature of controlled-mutability pointers: you can only mutate them via the means the types themselves allow, so if they do not expose any such options, they are effectively read-only. This is more of a simplification for practical purposes rather than restriction.

Comment: @usr The purpose of this rule is to align boxed value types and reference types. A reference type can go through one state to another only by calling its methods or modifying public fields. You cannot copy the contents of one reference type to another one; imagine what that would do to a string, for example. Value types have no identity on their own, but boxing gives them one, and their integrity has to be maintained like for classes. I remember some platforms, before generics, used objects True and False as boxed representatives of the two boolean values. Modifying them would break everything

Comment: @usr I might have simplified the restriction too much perhaps in my answer however; I will update it and add the reason.